# Equivalent of --env-file for build-arg?

Tags: docker

I'm building a Docker image using multiple build args, and was wondering if it was possible to pass them to `docker build` as a file, in the same way `--env-file` can be pased to `docker run`. The env file will be parsed by `docker run` automatically and the variables made available in the container.

Is it possible to specify a file of build arguments in the same way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such an option, at least for now. But if you have too many build args and want to save it in a file, you can archive it as follows:

1. Save the following shell to `buildargs.sh`, make it executable and put it in your `PATH`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   awk '{ sub ("\\\\$", " "); printf " --build-arg %s", $0  } END { print ""  }' $@
   ```
2. Build your image with `argfile` like:

   ```
   docker build $(buildargs.sh argfile) -t your_image .
   ```

Comment: This seems to return a "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument:

` docker build $(./buildargs.sh test_args) -t test_build -f Dockerfile .`

Where my test_args is just

`--build-arg PORT=4000`

EDIT: nevermind they must be separate by line and without the --build-arg:

```
PORT=4000
STUFF=HELLO
FOO=BAR
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is safe for build-arg's that contain spaces and special characters:

```
for arg in buildarg1 buildarg2 ; do opts+=(--build-arg "$arg") ; done

...

docker run ... "${opts[@]}"
```

Just substitute ***buildarg1*** and so on with your build-arg's escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Using linux you can create a file (example: arg_file) with the variables declared:

```
ARG_VAL_1=Hello
ARG_VAL_2=World
```

Execute the *source* command on that file:

```
source arg_file
```

Then build a docker image using that variables run this command:

```
docker build \
  --build-arg "ARG_VAL_1=$ARG_VAL_1" \
  --build-arg "ARG_VAL_2=$ARG_VAL_2" .
```