# How to use environment variables from file in Docker/devcontainer buildargs?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

Using VSCode devcontainer I want to dynamically set some build arguments for Docker in my `devcontainer.json`. Currently my `devcontainer.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "NodeJS & TypeScript",
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": {
      "VARIANT": "16-bullseye",
      "NPM_PROXY": "http://proxy.domain.com:8080",
      "HTTPS_PROXY": "http://proxy.domain.com:8080",
      "HTTP_PROXY": "http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
    }
  },
  "settings": {},
  "extensions": [
    // ...
  ],      
  "remoteUser": "node",
  "runArgs": ["--env-file", ".devcontainer/.env"]
}
```

With my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG VARIANT
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-${VARIANT}

RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends chromium

WORKDIR /usr/app

ARG NPM_PROXY
RUN npm config set https-proxy ${NPM_PROXY} -g

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium
```

As you can see, the `VARIANT` and `NPM_PROXY` args are used in the `Dockerfile`, but I need the `HTTP(S)_PROXY` for the build arguments as well. I'd like these definitions in `devcontainer.json` to get them from a `.env` file which resides in the same folder as the `devcontainer.json` and `Dockerfile`.

The `.env` file looks like this:

```
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
http_proxy="http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
https_proxy="http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
```

How can I achieve this? When I use `${localEnv:HTTP_PROXY}`, it will take the user environmental variable from my system. I don't want that because it has a different value, I want it to read the variable from the `.env` file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475672/140323550), so you can create a `.sh` file to read your `.env` and output a `args string` in the docker build command