# How do I interpolate ENV variables via env_file in docker-compose.yml to Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables, interpolation

I want to interpolate/pass *ENV* variables from **docker-compose.yml** to **Dockerfile**.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app-container
    image: app:latest
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: # Interpolation source files
      - ./env
```

**.env**:

```yaml
PORT=3000
```

**Dockerfile**

```yaml
FROM node:16

RUN echo ${PORT} # Output should be '3000'
```

Is there a way for me to make this work? I'm trying to find a way to pass `.env` files specifically for better organization. I also want to avoid using *ARG* as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .env File is read by docker compose if it is in the same directory by default. Variables can be used by ${key} in the compose preprocessing (=compose file). It shouldn't be mixed up with the env file handed over to docker run. This should be named somehow else. In my eyes it is a common mistake to mix both.

Build time variables can be given by args in compose, ARG in dockerfile and docker build --build-arg, runtime variables by environment (docker run - e) or env_file in compose (same like docker run --env-file). You want a build time variable (args). Therefore:

```
build:
  args:
    PORT: ${PORT}
```

If you want to use those values at runtime as well, add in Dockerfile

```
ARG PORT 
ENV PORT="${PORT}"
```

I would recommend to nor store credentials in envs neither hand down all buildtime variables to runtime automatically (even if there are solutions doing so).

Comment: Is there a way to automatically pass all .env file variables read by docker-compose as ARGs to Dockerfile? Also, is there a way to customize name of .env file that docker-compose should read?

Comment: docker-compose --env-file and I don't know a built-in way. There is always bash for sure. Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473951/equivalent-of-env-file-for-build-arg

Comment: @araisch To be sure, some vars are build-time, others runtime. However some are both -- consider compose that creates a database with a name, user, port, host, pw -- these are values needed at runtime, too.  Not sure why we would want to duplicate.  Also, some build-time variables are helpful at runtime, e.g. a mapped web port, environment, etc.

Comment: You could always hand down buildtime in Dockerfile with ARG PORT ENV PORT="${PORT}" to runtime (additionally to compose snip in my answer above) . But I wouldn't store credentials in env files. And I wouldn't do it automatically for all build time variables. But may depend on use case, I always assume a business thing and not a playground at home..