# Dockerfile RUN command cannot use heredoc with build args?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

When I set an env var and run:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
cat << EOF > foo.txt
this is ${TEMPVAR} and maybe this is too? $TEMPVAR
and that's all folks!
EOF
```

It generates `foo.txt` with the right values.

But when I try to use a similar method for dockerfile **RUN command**, it doesn't work?

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 postgres:16-alpine AS base

RUN cat << EOSQL > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql \
  create role ${ROLE1} with login password '${ROLE1PWD}'; \
  create role ${ROLE2} with login password '${ROLE2PWD}'; \
  EOSQL
```

When the image is being built, it fails, with the error:

```
1.188 cat: can't open 'create': No such file or directory                                                                                
1.188 cat: can't open 'role': No such file or directory                                                                                  
1.188 cat: can't open 'with': No such file or directory                                                                                  
1.188 cat: can't open 'login': No such file or directory
1.188 cat: can't open 'password': No such file or directory
1.188 cat: can't open '${ROLE1PWD}': No such file or directory
1.207 /bin/sh: create: not found
```

What's wrong with the RUN command? Dockerfile is being invoked by docker compose which picks up `.env` values automatically so not sure what else to try?

#### Update.

The suggested questions are irrelevant because I'm no longer struggling to pass build args to the dockerfile. I'm struggling to understand why heredocs don't work in dockerfile. I've evolved the code to:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "cat <<-EOSQL > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql \
  create role ${ROLE1} with login password '${ROLE1PWD}'; \
  create role ${ROLE2} with login password '${ROLE2PWD}'; \
EOSQL\
"
```

... and edited with vi to circumvent the docker formatter constantly indenting the `EOSQL`. I also added an extra line at the end. Still no joy.

Comment: What is `process.env` here? Keep in mind that you're operating in a shell context for the `RUN` command

Comment: Also, `RUN` is part of your image build. You need to provide dynamic data via build args and use `ARG` in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @Phil OMG.... I got confused and forgot this wasn't a node.js project. FACEPALM

Comment: I updated my script (and my question) and posted a different error. Will look into ARG, and build args as suggested - sounds like the missing piece.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of --env-file for build-arg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473951/equivalent-of-env-file-for-build-arg)

Comment: @Phil no because I am using docker compose not docker build directly. Secondly, my linux skills don't really reach the level of sed/awk etc yet, and I'd rather impl a solution i understand fully. Got further with ARG and switching to bash (`RUN  /bin/bash -c "..."`) but it's still failing with `/bin/bash: line 1: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOSQL')` followed by `cat: can't open...` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
RUN cat << EOSQL > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql \
  create role ${ROLE1} with login password '${ROLE1PWD}'; \
  create role ${ROLE2} with login password '${ROLE2PWD}'; \
  EOSQL
```

Isn't going to work because it's delivered to the shell as a single line (the `\`  at the end of each line means "turn this into a single virtual line"). Here documents only work when there are actual line breaks in your script, and there's no easy way to get that with this form of a `RUN` statement.

Why not just put your script in a file and `COPY` it into the image?

```
COPY start.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql
```

---

With recent versions of Docker (where "recent" actually seems to mean post-2021) there is actually support for [heredocs **in the Dockerfile**](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/), so you can write:

```
COPY <<EOSQL /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql
create role ${ROLE1} with login password '${ROLE1PWD}';
create role ${ROLE2} with login password '${ROLE2PWD}';
EOSQL
```

Comment: Thanks so much for EXPLAINING, I thought I was losing it, lol. Yes I was going to put it in a shell script, but realised that I would have to put the secrets in plaintext (it doesn't matter, these aren't big secrets). But it makes me wonder what I would do if the secrets mattered, and so I tried passing them directly into the target files without an intermediate file via a heredoc.

Comment: You wouldn't need to hardcode your secrets in the script. You could set them as build arguments, in which case they would be available as environment variables, or you could use [build secrets](https://render.com/docs/docker-secrets)...but generally you should be dealing with secrets at **run** time, not at **build** time (because you generally don't want to build the secrets into your image).